# Vue-Router not render when build mode

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I create app using vite (vue) and add vue-router@4.2.1

I run in dev mode ( pnpm run dev ) is work! but i build and run preview ( pnpm run build + pnpm run preview ) is not work

Link [Repo](https://gitlab.com/chunhakrai.b/vue-router-test)

You can test click href "TEST" in first page, Should be show "TEST PAGE"

[This image on dev mode (pnpm run dev)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzskR.png)

[This image build and preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psxqr.png)

Comment: did you try '{path: '/test', name: 'TEST-PAGE', component: import('../components/test-page.vue')},' => 'component: ()=>import(... ' ?

Answer (score 0):

From your sample code and the way you import the test-page component it looks like you want to lady load the route with dynamic imports.

When you want to dynamically import route components, you need to change     `{path: '/test', name: 'TEST-PAGE', component: import('../components/test-page.vue')},` to `{path: '/test', name: 'TEST-PAGE', component: () => import('../components/test-page.vue')},` . Check [lazy loading routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html) and [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)